# What does 'Chabo' usually mean

Tags: meaning, etymology

Does *Chabo* mean *rooster*? I learn it from the image search results on google. I want to know the origin or definition of *Chabo*, especially the reason why it means *rooster*?

This word comes from here

> http://csgostash.com/sticker/290/Chabo

If it is really a German word, my mistake to post it here.

Comment: Any reason for downvote this question?

Comment: Is it even an English word? Looking on Google mostly shows other languages. If you think it's an English work, please [edit] this to add quotes showing its use.

Comment: The only online reference for chabo is : http://it.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Chabo&defid=1206368.

Comment: As for the rooster, it is the name of a Japanese species. http://it.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chabo

Comment: @Josh61seems correct!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because *chabo* is not an English word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The Japanese bantam or Chabo is a breed of chicken originating in
>   Japan.

source:

[en.wikipedia.org](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_bantam)

[it.wikipedia.org](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chabo)